# Beanshell interpreter with javaFX

Tags: javafx, interpreter, beanshell

New to Beanshell interpreter. Why does the line that has comment *Does not work* not work?  I have used the instance.method with success before.

This is my first post on here, so excuse me if this is not the correct format.  Also, I have tried to find my answer on here previously with no luck.

```java
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import bsh.Interpreter;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class Troubleshoot extends Application {

    Group group;
    Interpreter inter = new Interpreter();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        group = new Group();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(group,1500, 700);
        scene.setFill(null);
        Button myButton = new Button("Enter Code");
        group.getChildren().add(myButton);
        myButton.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> event = new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try {
                    inter.set("instance", this);
                    inter.set("q", 5.0);
                    //inter.eval("float r = 5.0;"); //WORKS
                    inter.eval("float r = instance.twice(q);"); //DOES NOT WORK
                    Object qq = inter.get("r");
                    String sq = qq.toString();
                    float fq = Float.parseFloat(sq);
                    Text v = new Text("r: " + fq);
                    v.setX(700);
                    v.setY(400);
                    group.getChildren().add(v);
                }
                catch(Exception f){
                    Text u = new Text("You didn't assign the variables to a float."); 
                    u.setX(700);
                    u.setY(100);
                }
            }
        };

        myButton.setOnAction(event);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void buttonClick(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public float twice(float x) {
        return 2 * x;
    }
}
```

The code below does work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import bsh.Interpreter;

public class Example extends Application
{
    
    private int count = 0;
    private Label myLabel = new Label("0");

    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        
        Button myButton = new Button("Count");

        GridPane pane = new GridPane();
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10));
        pane.setMinSize(300, 300);
        pane.setVgap(10);
        pane.setHgap(10);

        //set an action on the button using method reference
        myButton.setOnAction(this::buttonClick);

        // Add the button and label into the pane
        pane.add(myLabel, 1, 0);
        pane.add(myButton, 0, 0);

        // JavaFX must have a Scene (window content) inside a Stage (window)
        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 300,100);
        stage.setTitle("JavaFX Example");
        stage.setScene(scene);
           Interpreter i = new Interpreter();
        try{
        i.set("instance", this);
        
        i.set("y", 7.0f);
        i.eval("count = instance.twice(y);");
        myLabel.setText(i.get("count").toString());
    }
        catch (Exception e){System.out.println("Test");}
        // Show the Stage (window)
        stage.show();
    }

    
    private void buttonClick(ActionEvent event)
    {
      
        
    }
    
    public float twice(float f) {return f*2;}
}
```

Comment: Is there an error message? I don’t know Beanshell but in Java the assignment `q = 5.0` would assign to a variable of type `double`, but then you’re passing that value to a method which expects a `float` parameter.

Comment: I changed the 5.0 to 5.0f and still got the same result.  There is no error message.  I am new to beanshell as well but if you are running a java program and use the Beanshell interpreter it does not give error messages.

Comment: *"if you are running a java program and use the Beanshell interpreter it does not give error messages"* This appears not to be true. If you actually display the stack trace from the exceptions you catch, you will see the error message and complete stack trace. These are reasonably informative: `Error in method invocation: Method twice( float ) not found in class'Troubleshoot$1'`

Answer (score 2):

Don't suppress error messages.

If you replace the `catch` block in `Troubleshoot` with

```
catch(Exception f){
    f.printStackTrace();
}
```

You will see a complete stack trace, including the message

> Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``float r = instance.twice(q);'' : Typed variable declaration : Error in method invocation: Method twice( double ) not found in class'Troubleshoot$1'

Note this `$1` at the end of the class name; this refers to an anonymous inner class (the one you defined as your `EventHandler`). The problem is that you are setting `instance` to the instance of the `EventHandler` class, and that class does not contain a method `twice(double)`.

To refer to the containing class, either set the `instance` variable outside the event handler, or use `Troubleshoot.this` to refer to the current instance of the containing class, or just use a lambda expression in place of the anonymous inner class (in the normal way you would do in Java 8 or later).

Any of these fixes will give the subtly different error message:

> Error in method invocation: Method twice( double ) not found in class'org.jamesd.examples.config.Troubleshoot'

(without the `$1`). This is because the method you have defined expects a `float`, and you are providing a `double`. Changing the type in the method fixes the issue. The following works as expected:

```
import bsh.Interpreter;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Troubleshoot extends Application {

    Group group;
    Interpreter inter = new Interpreter();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        group = new Group();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(group,1500, 700);
        scene.setFill(null);
        Button myButton = new Button("Enter Code");
        group.getChildren().add(myButton);

        EventHandler<ActionEvent> event = e ->
            {
                try {
                    inter.set("instance", this);
                    inter.set("q", 5.0);
                    //inter.eval("float r = 5.0;"); //WORKS
                    inter.eval("float r = instance.twice(q);");
                    Text v = new Text("r: " + inter.get("r"));
                    v.setX(700);
                    v.setY(400);
                    group.getChildren().add(v);
                }
                catch(Exception f){
                    Text u = new Text("You didn't assign the variables to a float.");
                    u.setX(700);
                    u.setY(100);
                    f.printStackTrace();
                }
        };

        myButton.setOnAction(event);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void buttonClick(ActionEvent event)
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    public double twice(double x) {
        return 2 * x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! I teach AP Computer Science (Java) but really don't have to do exceptions.  I need to brush up on the stack trace.

Comment: When I print the stacktrace, I still don't see the error messages (with an intentional error).  It doesn't bring up the terminal window automatically like System.out.println?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that question. The stack trace is printed to standard error. So if you're running inside an IDE, it'll be sent to the IDE's console (details are IDE-specific). If you're running from the terminal, it will show in the terminal. I don't know what you mean by "bring up the terminal window".

Comment: I had to manually set the console to be displayed.  Thanks again for all the help!